# Using Ack.vim on visual selection

Tags: vim, ack

Currently I have this mapping in my `~/.vimrc`

```
noremap <Leader>a :Ack <cword><cr>
```

which enables me to search for a word under the cursor.

I would like to search for a current visual selection instead, because sometimes words are not enough.

Is there a way I can send visual selection to `ack.vim`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can write a visual-mode map that yanks the highlighted text and then pastes it verbatim (properly escaped) onto the vim command-line:

```
vnoremap <Leader>a y:Ack <C-r>=fnameescape(@")<CR><CR>
```

This solution uses the `<C-r>=` trick that allows you to enter a kind of second-level command-line, which allows you to enter any vimscript expression, which is then evaluated, and the result is stringified and pasted onto the (original, first-level) command-line where the cursor is.

A slight disadvantage of this approach is that it commandeers the unnamed register, which you may not want.

Comment: A small tweak: instead of `vnoremap`, it's better to use `xnoremap`. The former also maps the keystrokes in "select" mode, which is usually used by snippet plugins. Read `:help mapmode-x` for details.

Comment: @AndrewRadev, good idea, although the map as written would not work for select mode, because the leading `y` would overwrite the selection and start insert mode. I suppose it could be made to work by writing a separate map for select mode (smap) and prepending the map arg with `<Esc>gv` to get out of select mode without doing any damage and then getting into (regular) visual mode, where the remainder of the map can take effect.

Comment: I meant that `vnoremap` would also map the keystrokes in select mode, and you probably don't want that. `xnoremap` would only map them in visual mode. Somewhat counterintuitively :).

Comment: Aha, I just read the vim help, and right you are! When I read your comment I thought you'd meant "latter" when you said "former", but that was my mistake. It's funny, you basically made the exact point I tried to make in my response.

Comment: Honestly, "latter" and "former" are some of the most confusing words in the English language. To this day, I still don't get who made them up. So yeah.

Comment: I used this to do a `vmap` for `:Rg` (package fzf.vim) and it worked great. Finally, I can visually select text and search for it easily. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

While bgoldst's answer should work just fine, you could also consider my fork of ack.vim: https://github.com/AndrewRadev/ack.vim

It comes with a working `:Ack` command in visual mode, and a few other extras that I've summarized at the top of the README.

Comment: A fork from 2015 and the original Ack.vim still doesn't have visual mode.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing this is the default behaviour of Ack.

Just do the following:

1. move your cursor on any word in *normal mode* (for instance, hit `Esc` button to enter in *normal mode*, you know...)
2. type `:Ack` with **no argument**
3. it will search for the word under the cursor

Usually I select text during a search in a file (for instance put cursor inside word and type `*` repeateadly) the type `:Ack` to look for that word in other files of the project.

Comment: To be precise, this behaviour is not related to visual selection or search. Just put your cursor on any word in normal mode and use `:Ack`, and it will search for the word under the cursor.

Comment: @Pierre-AdrienBuisson thanks, I updated the answer adding your contribution.